# Simple question regarding number of elements in cyclic subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a cyclic group with $N$ elements. Then it follows that

$$N=\sum_{d|N} \sum_{g\in G,\text{ord}(g)=d} 1.$$

I simply can not understand this equality. I know that for every divisor $d|N$ there is a unique subgroup in $G$ of order $d$ with $\phi(d)$ elements. But how come that when you add all these together you end up with the number of elements in the group $G$.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is just the well-known formula

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)=n\ldots !$$

The basis of this, and in fact of your formula, is that there is one single, unique subgroup of order every divisor of $\;n\;$ : this is one characterization of finite cyclic groups.

Answer (score 2):

Define $G_d = \{g \in G : \operatorname{ord}(g) = d\}$. By Lagrange's theorem,
$$
G = \bigcup_{d|N}G_d.
$$

Furthermore, the sets $\{G_d\}_{d|N}$ are disjoint: If $k \ne \ell$ then $G_k \cap G_\ell = \emptyset$, since we cannot have an element of order $k$ and $\ell$ at the same time. It follows that
$$
N = \sum_{d|N} |G_d| = \sum_{d|N} \sum_{g \in G, \operatorname{ord}(g) = d} 1.
$$

Comment: Hehe...apparently you had time enough to read that commment eventhough I deleted it after less than 5 seconds after I posted it (!), @Ayman Hourieh.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hehe, I just happened to see it at the right time I guess. It turns out the cyclic assumption isn't needed...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have one last question. Why does Lagrange's theorem give that 

& G=\union_{d|N} G_d&

I thought Lagrange's theorem only states that the number of elements in a subgroup divides the number of elements in the group.

Comment: @user112110 Let $g \in G$. Consider the cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle \le G$. The order of this subgroup is the same as the order of $g$, and it must divide $N$ by Lagrange's theorem.